# Getting TypeError comparing coordinates in Python turtle event handler

Tags: python, string, int, turtle-graphics

I can't figure out how to convert x and y into an integer coming from a string

```
import turtle
t = turtle.Turtle()
s = turtle.Screen()
t.penup()
t.speed(0)

def draw_grid():
    count = 0
    distance = 0
    while count < 5:
        t.goto(0, distance)
        for i in range(5):
            t.dot()
            t.fd(100)
        count += 1
        distance += 100
draw_grid()


def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):
```

Something is happening here?? Im not sure, and keep giving me this error:

TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'int' and 'str'

```
    X = int(x)
    Y = int(y)
    if -20 < X < 20 and 380 > Y > 20:
        t.penup()
        if 80 > Y > 20:
            t.goto(0,0)
            t.pendown()
            t.goto(0,100)
        if 180 > Y > 120:
            t.goto(0, 100)
            t.pendown()
            t.goto(0, 200)
        if 280 > Y > 220:
            t.goto(0, 200)
            t.pendown()
            t.goto(0, 300)
        if 380 > Y > 320:
            t.goto(0, 300)
            t.pendown()
            t.goto(0, 400)

turtle.onscreenclick(get_mouse_click_coor)

s.mainloop()
s.done()
```

Comment: When executing this code it shows the error message `AttributeError: '<invalid type>' object has no attribute 'onscreenclick' on line 42` that is caused by the line `turtle.onscreenclick...`. Can you please resolve this as I am not able to reproduce otherwise.

Comment: Please copy-paste the entire error message, including any backtrace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Except for a "AttributeError: '_Screen' object has no attribute 'done'" error when closing the window) Your code works as expected on my system (Apple OS X) without modification.  Below is my rework of your code for style and efficiency, see if it works any better for you:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

def draw_grid():
    for distance in range(0, 500, 100):
        turtle.goto(0, distance)

        for _ in range(5):
            turtle.dot()
            turtle.fd(100)

def get_mouse_click_coor(x, y):

    if -20 < x < 20 and 20 < y < 380:

        turtle.penup()

        if 20 < y < 80:
            turtle.goto(0, 0)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.goto(0, 100)
        elif 120 < y < 180:
            turtle.goto(0, 100)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.goto(0, 200)
        elif 220 < y < 280:
            turtle.goto(0, 200)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.goto(0, 300)
        elif 320 < y < 380:
            turtle.goto(0, 300)
            turtle.pendown()
            turtle.goto(0, 400)

screen = Screen()

turtle = Turtle()
turtle.penup()
turtle.speed('fastest')

draw_grid()

screen.onscreenclick(get_mouse_click_coor)

screen.mainloop()
```

You don't need both `mainloop()` and `done()` as they are the same thing (aliases.)